# SignalR behaviour: preventing long polling

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I'm wondering to use SignalR in my web-application (c#, mvc).

**Scenario**: my users giving me input and I processing it and show them back the results.
This processing can be very long. How long? let's say 3 minutes (depending on netwok traffic, usage, ... - cannot be predicated).
Currently, I doing this process in AJAX request for long polling. While AJAX is running, I display on screen: "Please wait".

Now I added to this scenatio a new *server limitation*: Since I'm using [CloudFlare](http://cloudflare.com), they are limiting me that each request must takes less then 100 seconds. Otherwise, they abort the request.

So, I'm though about this and decide to check the option to move into SignalR. Why? because SignalR can manage this long polling for me. And mostly use another approach (like sockets or other technics), which may avoid this 100 seconds server limitation.

I'm reading in SignalR website that they checking the client capabilities and decide with which technology to use.

**My concern**: Since CloudFlare is limiting request\response to 100 seconds, this can do problems to SignalR. Let's say the my client is client without any new web feature (like WebSocket or other). This could lead the SignalR to do long polling - which may failed.

Is possible to define SignalR to avoid long polling?
Or
How do you recommend to avoid this problematic case.

Comment: A good place to start would be the [documentation](http://www.asp.net/signalr).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SignalR allows you to configure the maximum amount of time the server will keep a long polling request open.

By default, the SignalR server will close poll requests that have been open for 110 seconds without receiving messages. Of course, if a message is sent to a client before the 110 seconds is up, the poll request will be closed when the message is sent. In both scenarios, the SignalR client will repoll when the server closes the previous poll (otherwise it wouldn't be long polling I guess).

You can lower the default timeout of 110 seconds during your application startup using [`IConfigurationManager.ConnectionTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.configuration.iconfigurationmanager.connectiontimeout(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
// Make long polling connections wait a maximum of 60 seconds for a
// response. When that time expires, trigger a timeout command and
// make the client reconnect.
GlobalHost.Configuration.ConnectionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
```

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#connectiontimeout